# Combinatorial interpretation of the number of subsequences of fixed length that preserve relative order

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be a finite sequence of objects of some kind, I've attempted to calculate how many subsequences of $(x_k)$ that preserve relative order have exactly $m$ elements. This means that if $x_i$ comes before $x_j$ in the subsequence, then $i < j$.

I did this by counting how many subsequences with the desired property there are in the sequence $x_k, x_{k + 1}, \dots, x_n$. If we add all of these counts for all $k$, we'll get the answer.

If $k < n - m + 1$ there are no subsequences since we're working with less than $m$ elements.

If $k = n - m + 1 - 0$, we have $1 = \binom{m + 0}{0}$ subsequences.

If $k = n - m + 1 - 1$, we have $m + 1 = \binom{m + 1}{1}$ subsequences, since we have $m + 1$ total elements, and we have to pick one to not place in the sequence.

This pattern continues: if $k = n - m + 1 - j$ we get $\binom{m + j}{j}$, until $k = 1 = n - m + 1 - (n - m)$, by the same argument, picking elements not to place in the sequence, what's left is in relative order.

So the answer should be

$$\sum_{j = 0}^{n - m} \binom{m + j}{j} = \binom{m + n - m + 1}{n - m} = \binom{n + 1}{n - m}.$$

I'm not sure if my logic is correct nor the calculation. If so, it looks like the answer has got to have some combinatorial interpretation which I'm not seeing.

This since the binomial coefficient at the end says that from $n + 1$ elements, I pick $n - m$, and that somehow counts the number of subsequence with the desired property, but I have $n$ elements originally, not $n + 1$.

Also, the formula looks very pretty if we write it in terms of multiset coefficients:

$$\binom{n + 1}{n - m} = \left( \binom{n}{n - m} \right).$$

So maybe the combinatorial interpretation comes from there, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by subsequences? I would assume, when $n=5$, $m=3$, and $(x_1,\dots,x_5)=(A,B,C,D,E)$, then the complete list of subsequences of length $3$ would be $ABC,ABD,ABE,ACD,ACE,ADE,BCD,BCE,BDE,CDE$. But this is only $10$ sequences, contradicting your formula of $\binom{n+1}{n-m}=\binom{5+1}{5-3}=15$.

Comment: You're overcounting, because at each step the element(s) you choose to remove cannot include the first one, otherwise the resulting sequence would already have been counted in one of the previous steps. For example, suppose $n=10, m=6$ and you're counting the sequences starting with $x_3$.  You have $8$ elements to choose from, so you have to remove $2$, but you cannot remove $x_3$, otherwise the resulting sequences would already have been counted in the step where you started with $x_4$ or the one where you started with $x_5$. If you adjust for that your count should give you the right result

Comment: However, there is a much simpler way to approach the question, which should be clear once you get the correct answer by making that small adjustment to your count.

Comment: @MikeEarnest you're right, those are the subsequences I'm interested in. Out of $n$ elements, I pick $m$ such that if an element if before another one in the subsequence, it also is before it in the original sequence.

Comment: @LeonardoLovera "Out of $n$ elements, I pick $m$ such that..." Well, isn't it obvious that the number of ways to pick $m$ out of $n$ objects is $\binom{n}{m}$? By the very definition of $\binom nm$? I think you are over-thinking this.

Comment: @A.J. Thank you, I've considered what you wrote and you're right! Since I cannot remove the first element, my sum is now $\sum_{j = 0}^{n - m} \binom{m + j - 1}{j}$ which after some manipulation results in $\binom{n}{m}$, surprisingly! And that has to be the simpler approach you mentioned in your comment, since this binomial counts the number of $m$-element subsets of the $n$-element set $\lbrace x_k \rbrace$, and since in sets the order does not matter, it counts the subsequences I want exactly once!

Comment: @MikeEarnest I adjusted my count as another comment said, and effectively the answer is $\binom{n}{m}$, the order preserving confused me and I did not realize that the own binomial does the job for me.